# Should I Create Index before or after Inserting Large Volume of Data?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, insert, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

Before posting my post, I have read a lot of such articles and posts, such as:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/index-creation-after-of-before-populate
https://nakulvachhrajani.com/2011/11/07/sql-server-performance-best-practice-create-index-before-or-after-a-data-insert/

However, my case is a bit different, that is the reason why I ask it here.

I am using SQL Server 2008. In my database, there is a table MyTable, with the following structure:

```
MyID (bigint)    MyData1 (bigint)     MyData2 (bigint)
```

`MyID` is an unique ID for each record. But I do not set it as UNIQUE when creating the table.

Then I use Visual C++ 2008/ADO to access the table, as expressed by the following pseudocode:

```
Create MyTable

// Method 1: Create Clustered Index for MyID here

// Part1: Insert data to the table
for (i = 0; i <= 500000; i++)
{
   Read CurrentID, CurrentData1, CurrentData2 from File1
   Select MyID from MyTable Where MyID = CurrentID
   if Found nothing then
     Insert(CurrentID, CurrentData1, CurrentData2) to MyTable      
}

// Method 2: Create Non-Clustered Index for MyID here

// Part2: Lookup data in the table
for (j = 0; j <= 900000; j++)
{
   Read CurrentID2 from File2
   Select MyData1 from MyTable Where MyID = CurrentID2
   if Found Then
     Do something
}
```

As you can see, my codes are composed by two parts, the first part is data insertion, but during the insertion, it will also lookup the table to prevent inserting records with duplicate MyID, the second part is data lookup, which will lookup the record based on MyID frequently.

To improve the lookup performance, I create index for MyID. I try the following methods:

1. Create Clustered Index for MyID, before the data insertion part.
2. Create Non-Clustered Index for MyID, after the data insertion part, and before the data lookup part.

To my surprise, method 2 will cause the data insertion part much more slower than method 1, which seems to be contract with the recommendation of "insert first, index next".

My question is:

1. Whether I should set MyID as UNIQUE when creating MyTable? If I set it as UNIQUE, then I do not need to lookup before inserting, but inserting record with duplicate MyID will fail.
2. I should create clustered index or non-clustered index?
3. Should I create index before or after data insertion part?

Sorry for so many questions. However, they are related. Also as there are many combination of these choices, I want to get some hints on which direction should I try, since each test will consume a lot of time.

Currently my test on method 2 has taken several days and still not completed yet, but it already taken much more time than method 1.

**Update:**

I have changed from "Select *" to "Select required columns only". Based on my test, it will improve about 1.5% speed.

Comment: You shouldn't select `*`, I guess, as this needs all the columns to be read, i.e. possibly not just the index. Try some constant or even using `EXISTS` like in `SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myid = ?);` (Note that in the subquery to `EXISTS` the projected columns aren't actually read, so `*` is fine *there*.) That might be much faster.

Comment: @stickybit, thank you. I have changed from "Select *" to "Select required columns only". Based on my test, it will improve about 1.5% speed. I will try EXISTS to see if it is better.